# how to avoid db query with django fragment cache

Tags: django, caching

I wonder what is fragment cache intended for. How can it help to avoid database query.

For example:

```
{% cache cache_key param1 param2 %}
...
{% endcache %}
```

The `param1` and `param2` are passed from client, I need to do some query from database before rendering the template.
How can I avoid querying db with the help of the cache?

It only helps to accelerate the rendering phase? DB searching is much more costing that rendering, right?

If the query is inevitable here, the cache is useless I think.

**UPDATE 2016/9/20**:

I do many queries in the view:

```
class SimeView(View):
    def get(self, request, param1, param2):
        data = {}
        data['param1'] = param1
        data['param2'] = param2
        ### a lot of queries to gather data 
        # ...
        ######
        return render(request, "some_view.html", data)
```

Seems that each request will go through the `get` function and do the queries in my code.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. The fragment cache will help you if your template rendering causes db queries, for instance if it accesses related items etc. If you're making queries in the view, then obviously it won't help you; you'd need to use [the low-level cache api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I do many query in the view to gather data and after that I render the template with that data. So I am confused about the fragment caching with my use case. Seems that It can not help me.